# JavaScript function doesn't change the textarea in Chrome&Firefox but works in IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I've a web page which include a JavaScript function to convert the multiple lines to a comma separated data. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add case</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function replaceSeperator() {
            var incident_box = document.getElementById("TextBoxIncidentID")
            var content = incident_box.value;
            //incident_box.innerHTML = content.replace(/\n/g, ",");
            var ctt = content.replace(/\n/g, ",");
            var lastchar = ctt.substr(ctt.length - 1);
            if (lastchar != ",") {
                incident_box.innerHTML = ctt;
            } else {
                incident_box.innerHTML = ctt.substr(0,ctt.length - 1);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea name="TextBoxIncidentID" rows="2" cols="20" id="TextBoxIncidentID" textwrapping="Wrap" acceptreturn="true" onmouseout="replaceSeperator()" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:Medium;height:60px;width:430px;margin-top: 5px;"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in IE:
[The line break replaced to comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HALFo.png)

But it doesn't working as expected in Chrome and Firefox:
[Line break replaced to comma at Dev Tool but it doesn't present on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfrpM.png)

Does any one know how to fix it? 
Thanks

Comment: use `value` maan!! not innerHMTL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `value` property. `innerHTML` is for another purposes. Even textarea has the closing tag, the inner content is the textarea value:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add case</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function replaceSeperator() {
            var incident_box = document.getElementById("TextBoxIncidentID")
            var content = incident_box.value;
            //incident_box.innerHTML = content.replace(/\n/g, ",");
            var ctt = content.replace(/\n/g, ",");
            var lastchar = ctt.substr(ctt.length - 1);
            if (lastchar != ",") {
                incident_box.value = ctt;
            } else {
                incident_box.value = ctt.substr(0,ctt.length - 1);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea name="TextBoxIncidentID" rows="2" cols="20" id="TextBoxIncidentID" textwrapping="Wrap" acceptreturn="true" onmouseout="replaceSeperator()" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:Medium;height:60px;width:430px;margin-top: 5px;"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a `;` at the end of

```
var incident_box = document.getElementById("TextBoxIncidentID")
```

Some browsers are more forgiving to this than others.